# Splunk dashboard limit multiselect input based on token

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I am populating Splunk dashboard input `ItemCategory` based on `Dashboard style` dropdown token, currently using `<eval token="form.ItemCategory">split("CAT","CAT2","CAT3",",")</eval>` to auto-populate multi-select input however user is restricted to specific items (as per eval definiton) and cannot deselect `ItemCategory` items (ex. should be able to deselect `CAT2`) as eval is refreshed with user click.

Having non-standard panels that are specific to `Dashboard style` dropdown token and would like to limit `ItemCategory` multi-select dropdown so charts are working as expected (as some group of categories are having different format of data) but to leave some flexibility for a user.

**Expected result**

With `Dashboard style` dropdown input of `Style1` limit or auto-populate `ItemCategory` multi-select input to `CAT CAT2 CAT3` but user should be able to pick/manipulate (or drilldown to one) any of `CAT` `CAT2` `CAT3` from `ItemCategory`

With `Dashboard style` dropdown input of `Style2` limit or auto-populate `ItemCategory` multi-select input to `CAT4 CAT5 CAT6` but user should be able to pick/manipulate (or drilldown to one) any of `CAT4` `CAT5` `CAT6` from `ItemCategory`

**Current Splunk dashboard definition**

```
 <dashboard version="1.1">
    <label>Dashboard</label>
    <fieldset submitButton="false" autoRun="false">
    <input type="dropdown" token="style" searchWhenChanged="true" id="style_input">
        <label>Dashboard style</label>
        <choice value="*">Default</choice>
        <choice value="style1">Style1</choice>
        <choice value="style2">Style2</choice>
        <default>*</default>
        <initialValue>*</initialValue>
        <change>
            <condition label="Default">
                <unset token="style1"></unset>
                <unset token="style2"></unset>
            </condition>
            <condition label="Style1">
                <set token="style1">true</set>
                <eval token="form.ItemCategory">split("CAT","CAT2","CAT3",",")</eval>
            </condition>
            <condition label="Style2">
                <set token="style2">true</set>
                <eval token="form.ItemCategory">split("CAT4","CAT5","CAT6",",")</eval>
            </condition>
        </change>
        <fieldForLabel>dashboard_style</fieldForLabel>
        <fieldForValue>dashboard_style</fieldForValue>
        <search base="baseSearch"></search>
    <input type="multiselect" token="ItemCategory" searchWhenChanged="true" id="ItemCategory_input">
        <label>ItemCategory</label>
        <choice value="*">All</choice>
        <fieldForLabel>itemCategory</fieldForLabel>
        <fieldForValue>itemCategory</fieldForValue>
        <default>*</default>
        <search base="baseSearch">
            <query>| stats count by itemCategory</query>
        </search>
        <prefix>(</prefix>
        <valuePrefix>itemCategory="</valuePrefix>
        <valueSuffix>"</valueSuffix>
        <delimiter> OR </delimiter>
        <suffix>)</suffix>
    </input>
    </fieldset>
    <row>
        <panel>
            <title>Count by ItemCategory</title>
            <chart>
                <search base="baseSearch">
                    <query>| stats count by itemCategory</query>
                </search>
                <option name="charting.chart">pie</option>
                <option name="charting.drilldown">all</option>
                <drilldown>
                    <set token="ItemCategory">$click.value$</set>
                    <set token="form.ItemCategory">$click.value$</set>
                </drilldown>
            </chart>
        </panel>
        <panel depends="$style1$">
        [...]
        </panel>
        <panel depends="$style2$">
        [...]
        </panel>
    </row>
    <row>
        <panel>
            <title>Results</title>
            <table>
                <search id="baseSearch">
                    <query>| inputlookup lookup.csv.gz | search $ItemCategory$ | table hostname itemCategory</query>
                </search>
            </table>
        </panel>
    </row>
</dashboard>
```